# How do I merge multiple pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe similar to the one seen below.

```
In[2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'P1': [1, 2, None, None, None, None],'P2': [None, None, 3, 4, None, None],'P3': [None, None, None, None, 5, 6]})
Out[2]: 
    P1   P2   P3
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  3.0  NaN
3  NaN  4.0  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  5.0
5  NaN  NaN  6.0
```

And I am trying to merge all of the columns into a single `P` column in a new dataframe (see below).

```
     P
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  4.0
4  5.0
5  6.0
```

In my actual code, I have an arbitrary list of columns that should be merged, not necessarily `P1`, `P2`, and `P3` (between 1 and 5 columns).  I've tried something along the following lines:

```
new_series = pd.Series()
desired_columns = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']
for col in desired_columns:
    other_series=df[col]
    new_series = new_series.align(other_series)
```

However this results in a tuple of Series objects, and neither of them appear to contain the data I need.  I could iterate through every row, then check each column, but I feel that there is likely an easy pandas solution that I am missing.

Comment: There is only one non None value per row?

Comment: How working my solution?

Comment: Waiting on requirements clarification from my boss, I’ll accept once I verify it works :)

Comment: Ok, super, I only think you forget :)

Answer (score 5):

If there is only one non None value per row forward filling `None`s and select last column by position:

```
df['P'] = df[['P1', 'P2', 'P3']].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
print (df)
    P1   P2   P3    P
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0
2  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0
3  NaN  4.0  NaN  4.0
4  NaN  NaN  5.0  5.0
5  NaN  NaN  6.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate solution:

So, if we are not column specific within the DataFrame to choose about then we can use bfill() function to populate the non-nan values in the dataframe across columns So, when `axis='columns'`, then the current nan cells will be filled from the value present in the next column in the same row.

```
>>> df['P'] = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
>>> df
    P1   P2   P3    P
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0
2  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0
3  NaN  4.0  NaN  4.0
4  NaN  NaN  5.0  5.0
5  NaN  NaN  6.0  6.0
```